# How to delete words or characters before or after other words or characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want these series of characters, or rather strings:

www.example1.com
www.example2.com

To become like these ones:

example1
example2

using Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you can use the "Regular Expression" mode while performing a "Search and Replace" in Notepad++.

Search for `http://www.(.*).com`, and replace with `\1`; ensure that "Regular expression" is selected in the "Search Mode" panel.

The brackets are used to create a "capture group", and the `\1` represents the contents of that capture group.  So, you are finding the whole address, and replacing it with what's found in between the brackets.

- [More info on Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [More info on using RegEx in Notepad++](http://markantoniou.blogspot.ca/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Replace* tool (in *Search* menu).

1. Replace `http://www.` with empty string.
2. Replace `.com` with empty string.